# Mutt client installation

Tags: linux, installation, mutt

I'm trying to build & install a mutt client on my Slackware (14.2). I'm following the standard `configure && make && make install` procedure.
Here are my questions regarding the topic.

1. How to check if all 3 steps (configure, make, make install) went right? Am i right that i can redirect std error to a file like that:

> .configure 2> configure_errors.log
>   make 2> make_errors.log

and then assume that if the appropriate file is empty (no errors) the corresponding step is successful?

2. What are the default options to the `configure` script? I can find a list of options with their meaning but can't find which are the default?
3. I'd like to install mutt in custom dir ($HOME/mutt) but the `--prefix` option seems not to work. When i add `--prefix=$HOME/mutt` to the `configure` script it end up getting mutt installed just in the dir from  which i issued the script (that is the dir where it was untarred). My `$HOME/mutt` dir is empty.

Answer (score 0):

1) The usual way to do it (or at least how I do it) if you are unsure it will work without errors is to do all steps separately, and just look at the terminal messages.

So do `configure`, watch it complaining about missing libraries, install packages for the missing libraries, do `configure` again etc. until it succeeds. Then do `make`, fix errors in the source files if necessary (hopefully not). Finally do `make install`, if necessary as root.

Redirecting standard error into log files sounds unnecessarily complicated, usually you'll see the problem right away. And the terminal can be scrolled up. I haven't yet run into a problem where I'd need to do that, though occasionally I have looked at the verbose log `configure` produces on its own (because it contains the test programs it attempts to compile) if I couldn't figure out exactly what was wrong from the error message.

2) I don't think there's a way to find defaults. You can look at `configure.in`, `Makefile.am` etc. to get an idea what it does if a particular option is not clear. Which option do you have trouble with?

3) In general, for self-compiled software, I recommend installing them into `/usr/local` using `stow`, as described e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325923/for-convention-in-which-folder-should-i-place-no-installable-applications). Installing into subdirectories of `$HOME` will only work if you are not installing any libraries or other stuff which will be already found in `/usr/local` by most parts of the system, because the search paths for that exist by default.

Unfortunately, all software handles installing a bit differently, even with autotools, so I don't know why it didn't install into the `--prefix` directory. What were the messages you got after typing `make install`? They usually tell you where it attempts to install everything. Sometimes parts or all files ignore the various prefixes, and get installed somewhere else, so you have to change `Makefile.am` etc. to make it work properly.

Comment: Regarding question #1 - I thought that there is a standard/convention the configure, make, make install scripts outputs separatelly "normal" messages to std out and errors (if any) to std error but as i gather from your answer there is not a case?

Comment: I actually don't know, because I never tried to redirect stderr - if there's an error message, no matter if printed to stdout or stderr, I want to see it, and I don't want it in a file where I need an additional step to see it. :-) But it's easy to test, just provoke an error (e.g. deinstall some necessary package) and watch what happens. Too lazy to test that now. :-)

Comment: The usual convention for stdout and stderr is that if the tool produces output you possibly want to redirect to a file, *then* errors go to stderr, because then you'll still see errors even if doing `tool > some_file`. But both `configure` and `make` only produce informational output, so I've no idea if they separate between stdout and stderr.

Comment: And the other convention is to use exit codes to communicate success or failure - that's why `&&` works. I've never heard of the idea "if there's no output to stderr, then the action succeeded". That may work for *some* commandline tools, but I'm pretty convinced it will fail for the majority of them.